# What is the correct way to output hex data to a file?

Tags: c++, hex, fstream, bmp

I've read about `[ostream] << hex << 0x[hex value]`, but I have some questions about it

(1) I defined my file stream, `output`, to be a hex output file stream, using `output.open("BWhite.bmp",ios::binary);`, since I did that, does that make the `hex` parameter in the `output<<` operation redundant?

(2)
If I have an integer value I wanted to store in the file, and I used this:

```
int i = 0;
output << i;
```

would i be stored in little endian or big endian? Will the endi-ness change based on which computer the program is executed or compiled on?

Does the size of this value depend on the computer it's run on? Would I need to use the hex parameter?

(3) Is there a way to output raw hex digits to a file? If I want the file to have the hex digit 43, what should I use?

`output << 0x43` and `output << hex << 0x43` both output ASCII 4, then ASCII 3.

The purpose of outputting these hex digits is to make the header for a .bmp file.

Comment: The endianess does indeed depend on what platform you execute the program on. And so does the size of int.

Comment: doesn't `output << 0x43` output "67"?

Comment: @user507078: But the expression `output < i` is not affected by endianess as the output is text only.

Answer (score 7):

The formatted output operator `<<` is for just that: formatted output. It's for strings.

As such, the `std::hex` stream manipulator tells streams to output numbers as strings formatted as hex.

If you want to output raw binary data, use the unformatted output functions *only*, e.g. `basic_ostream::put` and `basic_ostream::write`.

You could output an int like this:

```
int n = 42;
output.write(&n, sizeof(int));
```

The endianness of this output will depend on the architecture. If you wish to have more control, I suggest the following:

```
int32_t n = 42;
char data[4];
data[0] = static_cast<char>(n & 0xFF);
data[1] = static_cast<char>((n >> 8) & 0xFF);
data[2] = static_cast<char>((n >> 16) & 0xFF);
data[3] = static_cast<char>((n >> 24) & 0xFF);
output.write(data, 4);
```

This sample will output a 32 bit integer as little-endian regardless of the endianness of the platform. Be careful converting that back if `char` is signed, though.

Comment: They are explicitly sized integer data types, available from the <cstdint> header in most recent compilers. I used int32_t because it guarantees that it's 4 bytes wide, which just int doesn't.

Comment: I have tested with short instead of int and it seems that the file contains the swapped bytes. e.g. for a short of `0x01f7`, using `output.write(reinterpret_cast< char* >(&n), sizeof(n));`, the file contains `0xf701`

Answer (score 7):

You say

> "Is there a way to output raw hex digits to a file? If I want the file to have the hex digit 43, what should I use? "

"Raw hex digits" will depend on the interpretation you do on a collection of bits. Consider the following:

```
 Binary  :    0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
 Hex     :    4 A
 Octal   :    1 1 2
 Decimal :    7 4
 ASCII   :    J
```

All the above represents the same numeric quantity, but we interpret it differently.

So you can simply need to store the data as binary format, that is the exact bit pattern which is represent by the number.

**EDIT1**

When you open a file in text mode and write a number in it, say when you write  `74` (as in above example) it will be stored as two ASCII character `'7'` and `'4'` . To avoid this open the file in binary mode `ios::binary` and write it with `write ()` . Check http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs2604/fall00/binio.html#write

Answer (score 3):

> The purpose of outputting these hex digits is to make the header for a .bmp file.

You seem to have a large *misconception* of how files work.

The stream operators `<<` generate text (human readable output). The .bmp file format is a binary format that is not human readable (will it is but its not nice and I would not read it without tools).

What you really want to do is generate binary output and place it the file:

```
char   x = 0x43;
output.write(&x, sizeof(x));
```

This will write one byte of data with the hex value 0x43 to the output stream. This is the binary representation you want.

> would i be stored in little endian or big endian? Will the endi-ness change based on which computer the program is executed or compiled on?

Neither; you are again outputting text (not binary data).

```
int i = 0;
output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i)); // Writes the binary representation of i
```

Here you do need to worry about endianess (and size) of the integer value and this will vary depending on the hardware that you run your application on. For the value 0 there is not much tow worry about endianess but you should worry about the size of the integer.

I would stick some asserts into my code to validate the architecture is OK for the code. Then let people worry about if their architecture does not match the requirements:

```
int test = 0x12345678;
assert((sizeof(test) * CHAR_BITS == 32) && "BMP uses 32 byte ints");
assert((((char*)&test)[0] == 0x78) && "BMP uses little endian");
```

There is a family of functions that will help you with endianess and size.

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Byte-Order.html

> Function: uint32_t htonl (uint32_t hostlong)
>       This function converts the uint32_t integer hostlong from host byte order to network byte order.

```
// Writing to a file
uint32_t hostValue = 0x12345678;
uint32_t network   = htonl(hostValue);
output.write(&network, sizeof(network));

// Reading from a file
uint32_t network;
output.read(&network, sizeof(network);
uint32_t hostValue = ntohl(network);    // convert back to platform specific value.

// Unfortunately the BMP was written with intel in-mind
// and thus all integers are in liitle-endian.
// network bye order (as used by htonl() and family) is big endian.
// So this may not be much us to you.
```

Last thing. When you open a file in binary format `output.open("BWhite.bmp",ios::binary)` it does nothing to stream apart from how it treats the `end of line sequence`. When the file is in binary format the output is not modified (what you put in the stream is what is written to the file). If you leave the stream in text mode then '\n' characters are converted to the end of line sequence (OS specific set of characters that define the end of line). Since you are writing a binary file you definitely do not want any interference in the characters you write so binary is the correct format. But it does not affect any other operation that you perform on the stream.

Comment: Wait... so I don't have to worry about endiness if I use output.write() as you did? How? What if my computer stores it in little endian and somebody else's computer tries to read it in big endian? Also, thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Also : If Integers change in size, does that mean the size of the data entries in the header change as well?

Comment: @jwaffe: You **DO** need to worry about endianess. I was saying the way you were doing it with the `operator <<` was so wrong that it is not relevant as the output is text.

Comment: Right under your code for output.write(), you said `Here you do not need to worry about endianess (and size) of the integer value...`. That's what I'm referring to. Are you saying that I only don't have to worry about endianess if the value is zero?

Comment: @jwaffe: sizeof(int) is not defined to any particular size so you need to worry about it. Put `assert(sizeof(int) == 4);` into you code this will make sure it does not work when you port it to a new platform where this condition breaks. The size of .bmp file I am sure is fixed to a very specific size.

Comment: @ jwaffe: From the above text: **you do need to worry**

Comment: Huh... odd. I must have misread it. So, how should I account for endianess in my code? Do I just pick one? It seems as though .bmps are little endian. I could detect its endianess, then have it output the same, is that what you recommend?

Comment: @jwaffe: Added info about htonl() above. I am not sure if this will help with .bmp files. But it is a generic way of moving integers between platforms with different sizes and endianess of integers.

Comment: Also, when I use  `output.write(&i, sizeof(i));` for an integer i, I get an error from the compiler about trying to use an `int*` in place of a `char*`.

Comment: Are you sure about this network/host code? This function doesn't connect to any network, so host/network values don't make sense in this context. If I wasn't clear in what I needed, I just want this program to be able to work on most computers.

Comment: @jwaffe: The htonl() and family are the only functions I know of taking are of endlessness (the problems for internet are the same as problems for files). Unfortunately they do not work for you (as bmp was written by people on Intel machines that did not care about anybody else). Thus if you are writing this on an Intel (or similar clone) you are using little endian already. You can add another assert to validate: `int test = 0x12345678;assert(((char*)&test)[0] == 0x78);`