# Read a double from 32-bit address flash memory

Tags: c, pointers, types, type-conversion, cortex-m

I have a 32-bit microcontroller and have just written a double to the flash memory. I now want to read the double back from memory, but I am doing something illegal as the microcontroller goes to the hard fault handler.

First I tried:

```
double Flash_Read64(uint32_t address)
{
    return *((double *) address);
}
```

but this did not work. Is it because address is 32-bit and the (double *) expect a 64-bit?

I then tried:

```
double Flash_Read64(uint32_t address)
{
    uint64_t temp;
    double * tempPtr = (double *) &temp;

    //Increment address.
    address += 4;

    //Get MSB.
    temp = (*((uint32_t *) (address)));

    //Shift MSB to upper half.
    temp = (temp << 32);

    //Decrement address.
    address -= 4;

    //Get LSB.
    temp |= (*((uint32_t *) address));

    return *tempPtr;
}
```

but still not working.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
bool_t Flash_Write64Address(uint32_t address, double data)
{
    uint32_t MSB, LSB;
    uint32_t * tempPtr = (uint32_t *) &data;

    //Get LSB.
    LSB = tempPtr[0];

    //Write LSB to flash.
    flashStatus = FLASH_ProgramWord(address, LSB);
    if(flashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
    {
        DEBUG("Failed to write to flash at address: %u", (unsigned int) address);
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Increment address.
    address += 4;

    //Get MSB.
    MSB =  tempPtr[1];

    //Write MSB to flash.
    flashStatus = FLASH_ProgramWord(address, MSB);
    if(flashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE)
    {
        DEBUG("Failed to write to flash at address: %u", (unsigned int) address);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Show your write function also.  BTW: Does your platform have `uint64_t`?

Comment: Little Endian or Big Endian of your system? Maybe you can first take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451688/c-serialize-double-to-binary-file-in-little-endian)

Comment: @chux: Yes it has uint64_t.

Comment: Is it because address is 32-bit and the (double *) expect a 64-bit?, your system is 32bits, all your memory addressing is done in 32bits

Comment: I would have used a `union { double d; uint32_t uint[2] }` for decomposition and reconstruction.

Comment: I will try to use a union. It is usually a lot less messier also.

Comment: @tesseract I think (double *) must be 32-bit in the 32-bit system because it is a **pointer**

Comment: @Jerry_Y yes you are right, that's what I meant, all memory addressing is 32bits.

Comment: `double Flash_Read64(uint32_t address) { return *((double *) address);
}` may not work due to `double` alignment issues, which you do not have with the `Flash_Write64Address()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify and avoid alignment issues (which I think it is the alignment issue that is causing grief.)

```
typedef union {
  double d;
  uint32_t u[2];
} Xlate;

bool_t Flash_Write64Address(uint32_t address, double data) {
   Xlate x;
   x.d = data;
   for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
     int flashStatus = FLASH_ProgramWord(address, x.u[i]);
     address += 4;
     if(flashStatus != FLASH_COMPLETE) {
        return FALSE;
     }
   return TRUE;
   }

double Flash_Read64(uint32_t address) {
  Xlate x;
  x.u[0] = *((uint32_t *) address);
  x.u[1] = *((uint32_t *) (address + 4));
  return x.d;
}
```

---

[Edit]
I am supposing that `address` represents an address with quad-byte alignment (its least 2 bits are 0).  If `address` did not have `8-byte alignment` (its least 3 bits are 0) and a `double` access required it, then

```
return *((double *) address);
// or 
return *tempPtr;
```

would cause a bus fault.  If this is true, the above code should handle this issue.
Alternatively code could insure `address` has `8-byte alignment`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out memory alignment issues. This was the case. When writing/reading a double from a memory location where (address % 2) == 0, it works! The documentation also says that the memory is accessed as 16-bit so this makes sense. Thank you chux!